# Storing country specific(static) data in database or in an class in MVC2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

What is the best way to store static data in MVC application? Data like country and cities.

1- Should the data be stored in database and called everytime a view requests it and populate the dorp down?
2- Create partial view of countires and use it in different forms when needed?
3- Create static classes?
4- Create class and static method which returns the list?
5- Use caching?

Or any other idea would be appreciated.

Also the dropdown list should work with ajax, like selecting country should load the cities, selecting cites should load the region?

Hekim Başi

Answer (score 0):

MVC stands for Model View Controller. Controllers 'control' your data, they do something with it, views are pretty much html, to show your data to users. Models are what you are looking for here, they store data in a way you can acces easily. As soon as you get the data you want, you store it in a model, then acces (and maybe alter) that data with your controller and finally pump it to your view, so the user sees your application.

Comment: You are right kevin but sorry for not being very clear about my question i mean what will be the best way for such cases i mean static data should i call it al the time from db or is there any other way to handle static data lets says 251 lines country, 84 cities for example turkistan, and each city has its own regions...how should i handle that data

Comment: @Hekim If you know all that data beforehand, store it in a database. You can then acces the appropriate data when a user enters your application. If you do not know all that data (eg, you get the data as soon as a user enters your application) you should make a model class wich you know can hold the data, but gets filled at runtime.